# Buffer string with "intialiser_list"

Tags: c++, buffer

I'm really new to C++, heck even scripting. I'm trying to wrap my head around to understand this implementation of initialiser_list.

```
class Test
{
private:
    initializer_list<string>Texts;

public:
    Test(initializer_list<string> texts):Texts(texts)
    {
        for (auto text : texts)
        {
            cout << text << endl;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    Test testObj({ "one", "two", "three" }); 

    //testObj.add("four");
    //testObj.add("five");
    //testObj.add("six");
}
```

Now if want to add "four", "five", and "six" how do go about making them being overwrite the previous, lets say with an
// testObj.add("four"); // something like this. Again sorry I'm a newb. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Storing initializer lists is a probably a bad idea. They are not meant as storage, but ... well, to initialize things. What you want is `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Ok Thanks, was trying to play with c++ features. I will go about using that instead.

Comment: @ClarenceRajaratnam you can keep the initializer_list in the constructor, but if you change the Texts member to `std::vector<std::string>` then you are probably golden. https://godbolt.org/z/Yc1G1zE7d